# MongoDB 3.6 - $inc two fields at the same time with findAndModify or update

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have MongoDB 3.6 installed with the repo as configured in the installation guide. I have CentOS 7.

Now, I have this document:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a561e324f5b1e2c0066b568"),
        "owners" : [
                {
                        "owner" : "Juan",
                        "from" : "1990",
                        "to" : "1995"
                },
                {
                        "owner" : "Diego",
                        "from" : "1995",
                        "to" : "1997"
                },
                {
                        "owner" : "Alonso",
                        "from" : "1997",
                        "to" : "1998"
                }
        ]
}
```

I want to `$inc` the `from` and `to` at the same time with only one update. Can it be possible?

I am with:

```
db.guitar.findAndModify({
     query: {},
     update: {
         $set: {
             $inc:{"owners.$[element].from":1, "owners.$[element].to":2}
         }
     },
     arrayFilters: [{"element.owner":{$eq:"Juan"}}],
     new: true
})
```

with error:

```
2018-02-16T15:44:58.138+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "The array filter for identifier 'element' was not used in the update { $set: { $inc: { owners.$[element].from: 1.0, owners.$[element].to: 2.0 } } }",
        "code" : 9,
        "codeName" : "FailedToParse"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.findAndModify@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:724:1
@(shell):1:1
```

If I use update:

```
> db.guitar.update(
...     {"owners.owner":"Juan"},
...     {$set: {$inc:{"owners.$.from": 3333, "owners.$.to":4444}}},
...     {"multi":true}
... )
WriteResult({
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 52,
                "errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage."
        }
})
```

It does not work neither.

So, is it possible?

Comment: Can you include the "old syntax" in your question body.

Comment: Sorry I may overlooked something. Now it works. I may change the question to another related one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct update query would be:

```
db.guitar.findAndModify({
     query: {},
     update: {
             $inc:{"owners.$[element].from":1, "owners.$[element].to":2}
     },
     arrayFilters: [{"element.owner":{$eq:"Juan"}}],
     new: true
})
```

notice you don't need a set only a `$inc`, however `$inc` only works with numerical values so you will receive the following error:

```
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $inc to a value of non-numeric type. {_id: ObjectId('5a561e324f5b1e2c0066b568')} has the field 'from' of non-numeric type string",
        "code" : 14,
        "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
```

In this case convert the value to be numerical and try it again.

Comment: You are right. This is a `{$inc:{}}` syntax error. I tried with `update` and `findAndModify`, both works. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem is that even I specify `"multi":true`, `update` only updates the first record even when there are more records matching the query; `findAndModify` also updates only one.